# Calculating with aliases

Tags: mysql, sql

Simple question:
Can I use an alias to calculate with? Is

```
SELECT example1 / example2 AS ratio
     , SQRT(ratio) AS squareroot
FROM example_table
```

legal and are there special rules to it (defining alias before using it etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should define an alias before using it, so you either:

```
select example1 / example2 as ratio
     , sqrt(example1 / example2) as squareroot 
from example_table
```

or

```
select ratio
     , sqrt(ratio) as squareroot
from ( 
  select example1 / example2 as ratio 
  from example_table
) as tbl
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I figured I could use answer 1 in theory, but it isn't practical in my case since I have a calculation which requires me to use my alias multiple times... (solution 1 would make my query probably over 500 chars long)

Comment: OK didn't expect that to happen... Even when only using aliases, my query got 678 chars long. I don't want to know how long it would have gotten when solved differently